# Is there a way to adjust the width of UITabBar button items to fit more than 5 buttons on the screen?

Tags: ios, button, width, uitabbar, items

My buttons seem stretched, especially in landscape orientation.  I can't find a property to adjust either on the UITabBar, UITabBarViewController, or on the UITabBarItem's themselves.  (Of course, one answer would be to get an iPad...but that doesn't solve the need for a phone.)

For example, consider this simple [Tab Bar Example](http://www.screencast.com/t/tJ9g8kxjmrnz) - if I only could set the tab bar to auto-shrink as more buttons are added, or manually adjust the width to fit them all on the tab bar, I would be happy.

Comment: Can you explain what this is about?  I'm not sure what these things are because you haven't provided me with a context to work with and the tags don't give any information about the subject =/

Comment: Give us a screenshot, please.

Comment: Consider a UITabBar where I initialize views and tab bar items programmatically in the Tab Bar Controller's init function http://screencast.com/t/tJ9g8kxjmrnz  When it gets past 5 items, I automatically get More..., but in my app's case I only have 7 items, and they would fit if I could slim down the tab bar item widths.  I can't figure out a property or method on the tab bar controller, tab bar, or item to do this.

Comment: If I add tab bar items graphically in Interface Builder, it adjusts the widths so I don't get a More button.  That's what I want to do programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use the UITabbar with more than five visible buttons. You've got to write your own component.

Here at [significantpixels.com / The iPhone Tab Bar Lessons From Reality](http://www.significantpixels.com/2011/04/04/the-iphone-tab-bar/) is an article about the tab bar which explains in detail how to design your tab bar from a UX point of view. And the magic number of tabs is five ;)