# UITabBarController tabBar setItemWidth doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have six tabs and need to show them all without More button.[**jomafer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888389/how-to-change-the-width-of-uitabbaritem) answer says that `setItemWidth` does that. I called this in `AppDelegate` but it didn't work.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setItemWidth:self.window.frame.size.width/6];
```

I then called the above in `TabBarController` `viewDidLoad` but it still didn't work.
Even tried

```
[self.tabBar setItemWidth:self.window.frame.size.width/6];
```

But there are few like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807695/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-width-of-uitabbar-button-items-to-fit-more-than-5-b) which say that what I want is not possible using `UITabBar`. Is this true?

Comment: Yes this is true that you can not add more than 5 tabs in UITabBar. If there are more than 5 tab then the tab bar automatically add "more" for extra tabs. From where you can access the rest tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UITabBar does not support more than 5 items without the "more" button.

Do you really need 6 buttons at the bottom of the screen? They're going to be small targets. Consider rethinking your workflow if you have 6 buttons you'll need to constantly access.

If you definitely need 6, just subclass UITabBar - I'm pretty sure you just need to override layoutSubviews and change a 5 to a 6 somewhere.

There's also an existing UITabBar replacement project called [Infinite Tab Bar](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar) that might fit your needs, if you don't necessarily need all 6 buttons visible at *all* times.

Comment: Which property in layoutSubviews will set the number of tabs ?